# How can I delete all lines that do not begin with certain characters?

Tags: regex, vim, sed, text-processing, replace

I need to figure out a regular expression to delete all lines that do not begin with either "+" or "-".

I want to print a paper copy of a large diff file, but it shows 5 or so lines before and after the actual diff.

Comment: Why can't you just regenerate the diff and tell it to reduce the # of context lines?

Comment: For what I just suggested, the command is `diff -c 0 -u 0`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In VIM:

`:g!/^[+-]/d`

Here is the English translation:

`g`lobally do something to all lines that do NOT`!` match the regular expression: start of line`^` followed by either `+` or `-`, and that something to do is to `d`elete those lines.

Comment: if you want to save one keystroke: ':v' is a synonym to ':g!' :)

Comment: That saves two keystrokes! Shift, 1. Neat.

Comment: Although the answer is spot on, the original question was not vim specific. As reference, one can, however, do exactly the same with sed (`sed -e 'g!/^[+-]/d'`).

Answer (score 2):

sed -e '/^[^+-]/d'

Answer (score 0):

`diff -u <some args here> | grep '^[+-]'`

Or you could just not produce the extra lines at all:

`diff --unified=0 <some args>`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat your_diff_file | sed '/^[+-]/!D'
```

Comment: Agree for this particular case. I typically use cat when using a long chain of sed commands to incrementally filter out data. If I have too big a data file to begin with, I replace cat with head -100 and the remaining part stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "^[+-]" difffile >outputfile
```

Instead of deleting everything that doesn't match you show only lines that match. :)

Comment: You definitely need another caret and may not need "e" or quotes. This works for me: `grep ^[^+-]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something more complex in terms of regular expressions, you should use this site:
http://txt2re.com/

it also provides code examples for many different languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
%!grep -Ev '^[+-]'
```

does it inline on current file, and can be considerably faster than `:v` for large files.

Tested on Vim 7.4, Ubuntu 14.04, 1M line log file.

Lines that don't contain word: https://superuser.com/questions/265085/vim-delete-all-lines-that-do-not-contain-a-certain-word/1187212#1187212